# How to pass any android element to non-activity class and set onTouch for that element in that class?

Tags: android, class, android-activity, element, touch-event

I need to pass UI element reference to a non-activity class, no matter what type that element is. And then attach **onTouchEvent** to that element inside that non-activity class.

How can I do it? I have searched the internet but I didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the context along the constructor or the method call.
Example:

```
MyNonActivityClass myObject = new MyNonActivityClass(getActivity());
```

## MyNonActivityClass

```
import android.content.Context;
import your.package.name.R; // notice the R you should add your package
                            // infront of R it should be something like 
                            // com.example.myapp.R
public class MyNonActivityClass{
    private Context context;
    public MyNonActivityClass(Context c){
        if(context instanceof MyActivityClass){
            this.context=c;
        }
        /** you can do multi if else statements for multi activity classes **/
    }
    private void someMethodToHandleUi(){
        View v = ((MyActivityClass)context).findViewById(R.id.myView);
        v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            // rest of your code
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yamen thank you for trying to help me, but  the code you give .I can't make it work.
Here is the screenshot 
http://prntscr.com/gl5bdr

Comment: First a can't call findViewById simply context doesn't have that function
Second new OnTOuchListener can't be instantiated

I'w noticed that ObjectAnimator use object to get reference to element but I can't figure out how

Comment: Thanks it's working now, I found easier solution which doesn't require context, by passing reference as object to class WeakReference<Object> target; trough constructor and than get View view = (View) target.get();

Comment: @user2311265 the if condition is an extra thing in here xD just in case you needed this method to handle more than one activity (views from different activities)  using if cases here was the solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution that doesn't require context or if conditions, all I need to do is to pass element reference to class as object and than use WeakReference to pass reference to a View.

Here is the code:

```
public class NonActivityClass{
   private WeakReference<Object> target;

   public NonActivityClass(Object target){
      this.target = new WeakReference<Object>(target);
   }

   @Nullable
   public Object getTarget() {
      return target == null ? null : target.get();
   }

   public void doSomethingWithUIElement(){
      View view = (View) getTarget();

      view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {       
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            return true;
         }
      });
   }
}
```